# Resetting Pandas dataframe in iterable loop resulting in ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need help with resetting pandas dataframe within a for loop. Here is the psuedo code of my current logic -

```
import pandas as pd
df_out = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['col1','col2','col3','col4'])

for filename in os.listdir(directory):

    #some logic that results in dataset stored in a list called - output

    #output stored in dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(output, columns = ['col1','col2'])

    #some other logic that is used to get col3 using list called - col3_output
    df.loc[:,'col3'] = col3_output

    #some other logic that is used to get col4 using list called - col4_output
    df.loc[:,'col4'] = col4_output

    #note - col3 and col4 output cannot be derived from existing columns i.e. col1, col2

    #reset the lists to empty for next iteration of file
    col3_output = []
    col4_output = []

    #assign output to df_out
    df_out = df_out.append(df)

    #######################################
    ## ERORR OCCURING HERE
    #######################################
    #resetting dataframe or deleting data
    del df

#write final df_out to file
#some logic
```

I have tried resetting data frame using df.iloc[0:0] and dropping the new columns that I am creating but to no avail. I get the error -

**ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable**

Comment: My guess is that the assigment is done by reference. Tried to reset the two lists at the start of cycle?

Comment: Thanks @crissal. That would result in 'df' not defined error as in the first loop the variable wouldn't be created.

Comment: You can define cols_x_output outside the for cycle, then set them to empty list as first line inside the for, and then execute the rest of your code

Comment: I understand what you are saying. The problem however, though, is with the creation of new column 'col3', 'col4' for every iteration that I derive using different logic. That's why I need to drop the dataframe and then recreate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was hard and well earned lesson I learnt through this error debugging. After further investigation I realized the error definitely was not due to not being able to delete or empty the dataframe df. Both of them were working.

The error as it kept stating was happening during the logic to obtain col3_output list. I was not resetting it to blank for further iterations (in sample example I did but not in the original one). Another thing that I should have stated is the line number where it was throwing the error.

To anyone facing similar error, please check to ensure the size of list which is being used to add to the new column of dataframe. It should not exceed the expected length. This will result in the error.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correct you just want an empty dataframe?
if so `df = pd.DataFrame()`
would just overwrite the old one and make an empty df.

Comment: Am getting following error when I try that - AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'.

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(columns= ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
print(df)
df = pd.DataFrame()
print(df)

Sorry im new to stack overflow so i dont know how to insert code neatly in a comment.. 
But when i enter above code it prints an empty dataframe

Comment: Sorry, didn't work. Am getting same error as I posted above. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Hm, very wierd. i tried it out myself and this code returns an empty dataframe, what version of pandas do you use? 

`test = {'test': [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 6],
             'test1': [43, 43, 34, 23, 43, 23],
             'test3': [3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(test)
print(df)
df = pd.DataFrame(None)
print(df)`

Comment: Thanks @warmupp for your inputs. The error as I stated below was at completely different segment of the code. I was able to fix it.